# AngularJS Conventions

Tags: angularjs

I've built a webpage using html, css, javascript, and jquery. I just started learning Angular.js. My question is do I have to rebuild the site in order to meet certain angularJS conventions or is everything I will be adding for Angular unobtrusive to my previous built code?

Comment: IMHO - this is too generic of a question. This is especially true since you didn't provide information about what your website does or even how you use css, javascript or how you plan on trying to use angular. Long story short, you don't have to do anything to "support angular" but you are definitely going to need to write some code to use angular...

Answer (score 0):

It is actually recommended that you NOT use jquery with angular for starters. To get the most out of angular you will most likely have to re-architect your website. The reason for this is that Angular is a framework; jquery is a library. Their concerns are different.

> When we think in Angular terms, we think about:
>
> Views, not DOM elements
>
> Directives, not event bindings
>
> Models as a projection of view
>
> Functionality separation

See here for more in depth explanation: http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/angular-for-the-jquery-developer.html

Comment: Can I use bootstrap with angular? And aren't I just adding directives like <htlm ng-app> inside tags anyway?(so rebuilding the whole site is unnecessary minus jquery)  I'm sure theres alot more too it, but I'm just trying to understand

Comment: I'm saying if you want to really get all the advantages of angular you would probably want to rewrite. This doesn't mean you cannot use it. The ng-app directive establishes (along with ng-controller and related) the angular boundary and you can freely use whatever you like outside of that.

Comment: If twitter bootstrap isn't recommended then what would you recommend I use with angular to make things like buttons looks as nice?